# Prevent "You didn't submit a keyword" from prompting when search page opens? Also, injection protection

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-injection

Everytime I open/refresh the page it prints the "You didn't submit.." error. How can I prevent this and protect from mysql injection?

This is my first real mysql db search that actually works so go easy on me please. I just want to make sure that if I put it up, it doesn't get raped.

```
<form action='trytosearch.php' method='GET'>
<center>
<h1>My Search Engine</h1>
<input type='text' size='90' name='search'></br></br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search here' ></br></br></br>
</center>


<?php

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search'];

if(!$button)
echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
else
{
if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term too short";
else{
echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
mysql_connect("localhost","me_abc","pass");
mysql_select_db("table");

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

}

$construct ="SELECT * FROM listoga_db WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($construct);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.</br>";
else
{
echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{
$title = $runrows ['title'];
$desc = $runrows ['description'];
$link = $runrows ['link'];

echo "
<a href='$link'><b>$title</b></a><br>
";

}
}

}
}

?>
```

Comment: Anyone? I could use some help...

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
if(!isset($_GET['submit'])){
    echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
    exit;
} else {
    $button = $_GET['submit'];
    //Sql injection here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

     if(isset($_GET['submit']))
     {
           //Your DB code here and Sql Injection
     }
 ?>
 <form action='trytosearch.php' method='GET'>
 <center>
 <h1>My Search Engine</h1>
 <input type='text' size='90' name='search'></br></br>
 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search here' ></br></br></br>
 </center>
```